# pandas python cant read data with doublequote

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if there is a duplicate post, because I've tried some method which was found in google but I did not get solution for my problem.

I've sample data like this:

> kol1,kol2,kol3

> abc,"def",ghi

I've try to open the file with this syntax:

```
pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=',')
```

or

```
pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=',' quotechar='"')
```

or

```
pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=',', engine='python')
```

but I get a `dataframe` like this:

> kol1,kol2,kol3

> abc,"def",ghi NaN NaN

the value which was in kol2 and kol3 is merged in kol1.

Can anybody help me how to read pandas `dataframe` with separated file comma and have row with double quotes?

Comment: You should format the file data as if it was code (indented with 4 spaces). Currently the data cannot be simply copied and pasted, and I cannot reproduce if I try to type it.

Comment: the sample data, i write manual in csv file

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work in double-quotes so use single quotes.
If you want to use something like he's so use backslash '' in the sentence.
BTW it may be a bug try to reinstall.
I hope you understand.

Comment: may be you can do data cleaning, by removing some unneeded special characters using regular expression.

Comment: still doesn't work with singlequote and even i've try reinstall python and the package :D

Comment: Hmm it's a serious case